# Make default sbt configuration depend on another

Tags: scala, build, sbt

sbt provides a number of different [configurations](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Configuration.scala#L33) e.g. `Compile`, `Test`, `Runtime` etc. By default, `Test` depends on `Runtime` and `Runtime` depends on `Compile`, which means that `Test` depends on `Compile`.

In my project I've added a custom configuration, lets call it `Generators`. I would like to make it so that `Generators` depends on `Compile` and so that `Test` depends on `Generators`.

This first can easily achieved when instantiating the Generators configuration.

```
lazy val Generators = config("generators") extend(Runtime)
```

Is there a way to make `Test` depend on `Generators` given that `Test` is provided by sbt. Can it be modified or overwritten in some way?

Answer (score 1):

I actually spoke to someone at Typesafe about this, and it looks like you're out of luck. The semantics of the built-in test configuration are set in stone, as it is set up to mimic the test scope in Maven, and the test framework, etc, is written with the expectation of the exact behavior.

Even if we could somehow hack it, it would likely require adding a fake instance of the test configuration, and undoing all of the test configuration added by the JvmPlugin (the default behavior added by sbt), which likely will have unexpected consequences.

Having said that, you could modify the behavior of what sbt would do when you type in "test" into the shell, which you could achieve by:

```
test := { println("foo") }
```

or

```
test := (test in X).value
```